# Nested SQL Queries 3 levels

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, subquery

I am using MS Access and having troubles writing a query(s) to get my end result.  Maybe someone can lend a hand.

I have Projects, Tasks and SubTasks tables.  Each table has a related table for "Assignees".  meaning a project could be assigned to an employee but the child tasks could be assigned to a different employee and still further the subtasks could then be assigned to other employees.

Now, when displaying this on screen, and I query for an employee that has been assigned to any project/Task/Subtask.  I need that data to display but not other data.  So for instance if the employee I query for only has been assigned to a task, then that project and task should display, but no additional projects/tasks/ and no subtasks.  Likewise, if I query for an employee that only has been assigned to a subtask, then I only want to see the associated project and task.  I think I can complete this with a series of queries...i think... but is there a slick method I can use to create this data.

Simply a select query with a series of joins could possibly work, but it doesnt because when an employee has been assigned to a subtask only and not to a project or task.

Thanks for any assistance!

Updated with additional information:

Table Structures:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Projects](
[ProjectID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProjectName] [varchar](100) NULL,
[ClientID] [int] NULL,

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PM_ProjectAssignee](
[AssigneeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProjectID] [int] NULL,
[EmployeeID] [int] NULL,

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PM_ProjectTasks](
[ProjectTaskID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProjectID] [int] NULL,
[TaskID] [smallint] NULL,

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PM_TaskAssignee](
[AssigneeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProjectTaskID] [int] NULL,
[EmployeeID] [int] NULL,

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PM_ProjectSubTasks](
[ProjectSubTaskID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProjectTaskID] [int] NULL,
[SubTaskDesc] [varchar](255) NULL,

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PM_SubTaskAssignee](
[AssigneeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProjectSubTaskID] [int] NULL,
[EmployeeID] [int] NULL,
```

With regards to queries I have tried...alot.  I was implementing a scenario where I ended up with about a half dozen different queries all culminating into one (some of the queries where built with code to allow filtering)  However the last one tried was:

```
SELECT  ProjectID, ProjectName, EmployeeID, ProjectTaskID, EmployeeID, Association, ProjectSubTaskID, EmployeeID
FROM (qrTest3_Project LEFT JOIN qrTest2_Task ON qrTest3_Project.ProjectID = qrTest2_Task.ProjectID) LEFT JOIN qrtest1_SubTask ON qrTest2_Task.ProjectTaskID = qrtest1_SubTask.Association
WHERE (((qrTest3_Project.EmployeeID)=8)) OR (((qrTest2_Task.EmployeeID)=8)) OR (((qrtest1_SubTask.EmployeeID)=8));
```

the above query included other queries that simply joined each project/task/subtask to their respective assignee table.  I can post those as well if needed.

I hope that provides the additional information you need?  If not, happy to provide more.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO)!  When asking a question on how to it helps to provide table structure, columns, expected reuslts and how tables relate.  In addition provide what you've tried.  We try to avoid writing the code for you, but are all to happy to help once you get stuck.  So if you could update your question with table structure, how the relate, desired results, and sample data as well as what you've tried, we'll do our best to help out.  As it stands, it's difficult to help as we don't know columns, expected results and sample data!

Comment: MS Access doesn't have schemas (`dbo`), `IDENTITY`, 'INT' or 'VARCHAR'. This is SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have figured it out..as I sort of suspected, I was making it a bit more difficult then it needed to be.  Simply joins really with criteria gives me the data I need and can work with.

```
SELECT PM_ProjectAssignee.ProjectID, PM_ProjectTasks.ProjectTaskID, PM_ProjectSubTasks.ProjectSubTaskID 
FROM (((PM_ProjectAssignee
 LEFT JOIN PM_ProjectTasks
 ON PM_ProjectAssignee.ProjectID = PM_ProjectTasks.ProjectID)
 LEFT JOIN PM_ProjectSubTasks
 ON PM_ProjectTasks.ProjectTaskID = PM_ProjectSubTasks.ProjectTaskID)
 LEFT JOIN PM_TaskAssignee
 ON PM_ProjectTasks.ProjectTaskID = PM_TaskAssignee.ProjectTaskID)
 LEFT JOIN PM_SubTaskAssignee
 ON PM_ProjectSubTasks.ProjectSubTaskID = PM_SubTaskAssignee.ProjectSubTaskID 
WHERE (((PM_ProjectAssignee.EmployeeID)=14))
 OR (((PM_TaskAssignee.EmployeeID)=14))
 OR (((PM_SubTaskAssignee.EmployeeID)=14))
GROUP BY PM_ProjectAssignee.ProjectID, PM_ProjectTasks.ProjectTaskID, PM_ProjectSubTasks.ProjectSubTaskID;
```

Comment: This would be much more readable with table aliases (pa,pt,pst,ta,sta) and no parentheses.